# Googlesheets: I need to assign a script to textbox that sends an email to an email address located in another spreadsheet

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm sure this will be a frustrating post for some and I'm very sorry. I don't have any coding background and this will be one of the first scripts I've ever attempted. Thank you again for the help!

What I need to accomplish is to assign a script to a text box that sends an email with the address located in another spreadsheet.

Here is the setup: Picture 1. This is the spreadsheet and tab where I want the email address to be sent from using the textbox (with the E) located to the right of the "In-Game Name"

Picture 1.) https://i.stack.imgur.com/miyFZ.jpg

The "In-Game Name" is already being imported from a separate spreadsheet. I have the url for this separate spreadsheet located in a separate tab of the current spreadsheet as you can see by Picture 2.

Picture 2 (left-side) and picture 3 (right-side) because my reputation isn't 10: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUY6u.jpg

You can see the data I'm importing from the second spreadsheet in picture 3 ("in-game name" and "prestige". I do not want to have the email address imported in this manner however.

I would like a script that sends an email from the main spreadsheet and pulls the email address from the second using the spreadsheet key url in the "Player Key Input" tab.

I have a sample of code that tries to accomplish this is currently only serving as comedic relief to angst from this matter.

Once again, I'm sorry if this was a poorly written/explained question. I'm awful with coding. I really appreciate any input!

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Is the main spreadsheet `Test Prestige Calculator` or is that the spreadsheet referenced on `Player Key Input`? Do you need this to work for only that one player `The living Tribunal`? Why are there no player names on the `Player Key Input` sheet? What should be the content of the email? Also maybe you could post the code you have so far.

Answer (score 1):

The question "To pull the email address from another spreadsheet" I would use a formula to have it copied over. Then assign a script to email the address. I am not sure how you would pull info from another sheet via script.

The below formula will pull the spreadsheet data that is in A1 to the cell you assign.

```
=IMPORTRANGE("YOURSHEETID","Sheet1!A1:A")
```

Answer (score 1):

We were able to get this to work using this script:

```
    /**
 * This is a utility function that sends an email.
 * It requires a To address, a Subject, and the message Body.
 */
function sendEmail(to, subject, body) {
  // The Reply To address is the default address that appears when a user replies to the email.
  // If not set to a bogus email, it probably defaults to the owner of the sheet!
  var replyTo = "donotreply@mail.com"

  // Send the email!
  MailApp.sendEmail(to, replyTo, subject, body)
}


/**
 * This function is an example of a boilerplate message that you can send.
 * You could duplicate this function for other types of messages.
 */
function sendAllianceMessageToUser(row) {
  var user = getUserInfoFromRow(row);

  sendEmail(user.email, "MCOC Alert", user.name+",\n\nPlease log on to MCOC and check AQ/AW!");
}


/**
 * This utility function will retrieve a user's info when supplied with a row number.
 * The row number must match the rows on the "Roster/Prestige" sheet.
 * This function will not need to change unless the structure of the sheets change.
 */
function getUserInfoFromRow(row) {
  // Keep a reference to the current active sheet
  //var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1McfUWHPCgh7XWtLgZX6mcnLs_o1MQprBOKbHiwNsVEo').getSheetByName('Roster/Prestige');

  // Grab the sheet key in the row that was provided. (In this case, column L)
  //var skey = sheet.getRange('L'+row).getValue();
  var skey = sheet.getRange('L4').getValue();

  Logger.log(skey);

  // Open the remote sheet using the ID that was retrieved earlier.
  var remote = SpreadsheetApp.openById(skey).getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  // Grab the necessary cell values
  var ign   = remote.getRange('C2').getValue();
  var email = remote.getRange('C4').getValue();

  var user = new Object();
  user.name = ign;
  user.email = email;
  user.sheet_key = skey;

  return user;
}


/**
 * These functions are generic image click handlers for each image.
 * Each image will call a function based on which row it is placed over.
 * MOVING IMAGES WILL BREAK THIS!
 */
function row3_clicked() { sendAllianceMessageToUser('3'); }
function row4_clicked() { sendAllianceMessageToUser('4'); }
function row5_clicked() { sendAllianceMessageToUser('5'); }
function row6_clicked() { sendAllianceMessageToUser('6'); }
function row7_clicked() { sendAllianceMessageToUser('7'); }
function row8_clicked() { sendAllianceMessageToUser('8'); }
function row9_clicked() { sendAllianceMessageToUser('9'); }
function row10_clicked() { sendAllianceMessageToUser('10'); }
function row11_clicked() { sendAllianceMessageToUser('11'); }
function row12_clicked() { sendAllianceMessageToUser('12'); }
function row13_clicked() { sendAllianceMessageToUser('13'); }
function row14_clicked() { sendAllianceMessageToUser('14'); }
function row15_clicked() { sendAllianceMessageToUser('15'); }
function row16_clicked() { sendAllianceMessageToUser('16'); }
function row17_clicked() { sendAllianceMessageToUser('17'); }
function row18_clicked() { sendAllianceMessageToUser('18'); }
function row19_clicked() { sendAllianceMessageToUser('19'); }
function row20_clicked() { sendAllianceMessageToUser('20'); }
function row21_clicked() { sendAllianceMessageToUser('21'); }
function row22_clicked() { sendAllianceMessageToUser('22'); }
function row23_clicked() { sendAllianceMessageToUser('23'); }
function row24_clicked() { sendAllianceMessageToUser('24'); }
function row25_clicked() { sendAllianceMessageToUser('25'); }
function row26_clicked() { sendAllianceMessageToUser('26'); }
function row27_clicked() { sendAllianceMessageToUser('27'); }
function row28_clicked() { sendAllianceMessageToUser('28'); }
function row29_clicked() { sendAllianceMessageToUser('29'); }
function row30_clicked() { sendAllianceMessageToUser('30'); }
function row31_clicked() { sendAllianceMessageToUser('31'); }
function row32_clicked() { sendAllianceMessageToUser('32'); }

function test() {
  sendAllianceMessageToUser('4'); // Testing!
}
```